# Batch script move file with rename source file if it exist in destination folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need move file **test1.txt** from C:\temp\ to D:\temp\ (for example). If the file already exist in destination folder D:\temp\ with same name, i want to *move and rename* source file to test1.txt~.
Is it possible to further simplify or optimize the script?

```
move c:\temp\test1.txt d:\temp\test1.txt~ || echo No | move /-Y c:\temp\test1.txt d:\temp\test1.txt
```

I need a similar Linux command for Windows:

```
test -d DestinationFolder || mkdir -p DestinationFolder && mv -bfv SourceFile DestinationFolder
```

Comment: Use [`if exist`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) to check whether the file already exists at the destination. Anyway, what if the new name also already exists? Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15518628) (replacing `copy` by `move` should not be a big deal); instead of numbering you could just append strings like `~`, `~~`, etc. (this would be easy to implement in the linked answer)

Comment: @aschipfl I need not only "copying all files without overwriting" i need "move and ***rename*** source file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **commandA && commandB**       Run commandA, if it succeeds then run
>   commandB

```
echo No | move /-Y c:\temp\test1.txt d:\temp\test1.txt && move c:\temp\test1.txt d:\temp\test1.txt~
```

I think it will be right.